# Scrapy: Using FormRequests to handle javascript doPostBack functions

Tags: python, asp.net, scrapy

I have a clickable link on a dynamically created page, that looks like:

```
<td align="left"><a id="ucResultsGrid_X77" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ucResultsGrid$X77&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;webProperty.aspx?stype=id&amp;s=67&amp;time=201606071553023&amp;id=X77&quot;, false, true))" style="text-decoration:underline;">View Property</a></td><td align="right">X77</td>
```

After inspecting the page source, it appears that  this submits to:

```
<form name="searchForm" method="post" action="./webSearch.aspx?cad&amp;stype=id&amp;s=67&amp;time=201606071512012" id="searchForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/really long string />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['searchForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.searchForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

I've been reading through http://harman-clarke.co.uk/answers/javascript-links-in-scrapy.php and http://cpuknows.com/2015/09/12/scrapy/ . from these and other sources (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#what-s-this-huge-cryptic-viewstate-parameter-used-in-some-forms and https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/04/20/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-april-2016-edition/)

I've produced the following spider function:

```
def parse_third_request(self, response):

    item = response.meta['item'] 
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response,formname='searchForm',callback=self.parse_detail_page,meta={'item': item})
```

However I'm not clear on how to set the formdata dictionary mentioned in http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-subclasses . In this case I'm clicking a link not filling a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the final idea is to replicate a Request, not really replicate a "click", which could involve several requests or just internal javascript processing with the actual response.

`formdata` is just another argument you can fill in that FormRequest, the final idea behind `from_response` is to just create the request specified on the Form you set, and by default gets all of the already set up `input` tags, with their `name` and `value` (just like a normal form request works).

There are some `input` tags that don't have information on the `value` attribute, which are normally filled later by user input, you need to check which specific parameters are being sent once you try to replicate that request, and pass those parameters on the `formdata` dictionary.